# Tips to Improve the QA Process in a Project...?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, qa-role

What can be some solid tips and suggestions to improve whole QA/Testing process in a project. I am testing a financial web application. What are the testing areas in which we can improve the process and minimize waste.

Please suggest improvement ideas in some areas:

- UI testing
- Security testing
- Test team communication.
- Requirement documents.
- Usability testing.
- Version control tools.
- Test management tools.
- Agile testing.
- Test case/scenarios improvement.
- Defect reporting improvements.

Any other QA process improvement/methodology/tools in general that can streamline the testing effort and increase productivity and ROI  drastically?

Comment: It's hard to suggest improvements w/o knowing what you're doing.  This question is very general, and can't really be answered.  You might be better off asking your team what they see as pain points, areas they think coverage is weak, etc, and going from there . . .

Comment: Downvoted because it is too broad.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to follow [STLC](http://www.guru99.com/software-testing-life-cycle.html) if you want to test any software/Website properly with software testing standards.STLC is same for all. It does not matter what you are testing so STLC is base to start and complete testing with quality.

**Manual Testing** - In most of application there are some areas which really need manual testing. So you need to find out that how much manual testing your web app. need.

**Automation Testing** - It is very useful to create automate test scripts which help to reduce testing time , resource and provide reliable result if you write correct script.So when you say how can you minimize process then I like to say that automation testing is good for repeated things in app. It also helps in regression testing.

So , Before start testing if you define that how much manual testing we will need , for which functionality we will do automated script then it will help you to get time estimation for that app. testing. Also make sure that you can estimate approx. time for any app. testing only if requirement are fixed. Now a days , it is common that requirements are changing very frequently which is not good to product top quality result.

Which testing you need to do for your web application it is really depends on application concept. Some web app. require only functional & non-functional testing , some require security testing also , some require other testings and a lot more.

In your case for "Financial Web application" , you should do testings like functional , non-functional , security , smoke , usability etc. If you think that there will be lot of traffic on your site when you do LIVE it , then you can also do **Load Testing** to measure your app. capacity.

You should create Test cases , Test scenarios and Bug report which makes testing more standard. Also it is require to update test cases regularly when requirement changes otherwise it never help to find new bugs.

**Useful automation tools :**

1 - Selenium with web driver [For functionality testing]

2 - Jmeter [For Load testing]

Also make sure that before start any testing , you must have full understanding of web app. which you are going to test. So requirement understanding is very important.

Hope this help you to minimize and set proper testing process.

Answer (score 2):

An area missed in earlier answers is working with your development team. You need to ensure that not only the lead, but each member of the test team has a good relationship with the development tea, counterparts. The developers are your greatest allies. Get the devs to write some more robust unit tests. Explain and have them buy off on your test plans and strategy. Ensure there's good communication between the disciplines.

For instance, the item around UI automation will be painful if the test team write automation against the UI as-is, and mostly it works, and then in the next sprint the developers changed ids of elements which would break your automation.

Make sure you have a clear and open channel of communication and partnership with the development team.

Answer (score 1):

Please identify the

- Different types of testing that you perform for the application
- Nature of bugs logged
- Types Regression Bug Trend How Early does tests find bugs
- How many priority bugs you find in early cycles
- What are the tools that QA uses to identify / report issues, Exceptions

You need to identify your current state, pain points. Start Fixing areas based on test techniques, coverage, bugs, fixes etc.. It need to evolve as practices (continuously) each week. Daily Stand-up can establish these changes are followed, implemented and measured.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have a pretty nice list of area's where improvements can be found I think the next step is to find the most important thing to improve. I would focus on getting a [continuous improvement process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continual_improvement_process) going. Possible roads are to introduce recurring [retrospectives](http://www.vanreijmersdal.nl/589/continuous-improvement-with-retrospectives/) to identify parts of the process that need improvement.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very broad question. You may use some of these tools:

1. Agile/Scrum project management tool Version One. They have free and paid versions. I find this project management to be very effective and user friendly.
2. When choosing for bug tracking tool, find the best match for your team. Jira is one of the best one out there.
3. Mobile/Device Testing
4. You can use Google Emulator for free, built in Google Chrome Browser
5. Git hub or SVN (Personally like Git hub)
6. You might want to automate your stable test cases for regression testing. Selenium IDE, Webdriver is a good one or Sahi.